# Slick slider slides is jerking after set custom width

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have tried this code but the slides are jerking after scroll.

i have added this css for animation but after clicking on next slid width change is look like jerking

```
<style>
    .home-slider .slick-track .slick-current, .slick-track .slick-active {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
</style>

$('.home-slider').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1000,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        nextArrow: '<span class="slick-arrow next"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" height="48" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1"><polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline></svg></span>',
        prevArrow: '<span class="slick-arrow prev"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" height="48" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1"><polyline points="15 18 9 12 15 6"></polyline></svg></span>',

    });

    $('.home-slider').on('setPosition', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        var window_width = screen.width;
        var first_slid = ( window_width * 30 ) / 100;
        var second_slid = ( window_width * 70 ) / 100;

        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-slide.slick-active').css('min-width', second_slid);
        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-slide.slick-active').css('width', second_slid);
        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-current.slick-active').css('min-width', first_slid);
        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-current.slick-active').css('width', first_slid);
    });
```

```js
    
            $(document).ready(function(){       
$('.home-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 700,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows:false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
 });
     $('.home-slider').on('setPosition', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        var window_width = screen.width;
        var first_slid = ( window_width * 30 ) / 100;
        var second_slid = ( window_width * 70 ) / 100;

        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-slide.slick-active').css('min-width', second_slid);
        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-slide.slick-active').css('width', second_slid);
        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-current.slick-active').css('min-width', first_slid);
        $('.home-slider .slick-track').children('.slick-current.slick-active').css('width', first_slid);
    });
        });
```

```css
img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="home-slider">
   <div><img src="http://yesofcorsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Insects-In-The-Rain-Best-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="image1"></div>
      <div><img src="http://yesofcorsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Insects-In-The-Rain-Best-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="image1"></div>
         <div><img src="http://yesofcorsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Insects-In-The-Rain-Best-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="image1"></div>
            <div><img src="http://yesofcorsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Insects-In-The-Rain-Best-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="image1"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

i have added this css for animation but after clicking on next slid width change is look like jerking
i have added this css for animation but after clicking on next slid width change is look like jerking
i have added this css for animation but after clicking on next slid width change is look like jerking

Comment: So what's your issue?  How to render the slider (as per title, seems you've already managed that!)  or How to stop it being jerky?    Please [edit] title/question accordingly.

Comment: It's unclear what *"jerking after scroll"* means without a runable snippet.    Do you mean they jerk *as* you scroll?  Or, after you finish scrolling, they then start bouncing around?   For the first, you could try *debounce* on the `setPosition` event.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem based on the information provided and following the [slick.js documentation](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/). The question requires far too much guesswork and should be updated.

Comment: updated title as per feedback

Comment: Thanks for updating question.  Please also explain "jerky" as it appears to behave as expected and similar to most sliding carousels.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.